# Using command ECHO in CMD

Tags: cmd, echo

I am trying to echo a command to another Batch file.

```
echo timeout 5 >nul >> Make.bat
```

It just shows `timeout 5`
I tried do something like this:

```
echo "timeout 5 >nul" >> Make.bat
```

Now it shows

```
"timeout 5 >nul"
```

Now i got `>nul`
But i don't want the `""` to not show

I want it to show `timeout 5 >nul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a caret(`^`) character to escape the `>` character.

```
echo timeout 5 ^> nul >> Make.bat
```